# Which one of these two ISO 639-2 code refers to Traditional Chinese, chi or zho?

Tags: traditional-characters

On a database file, the designer uses **chi** and **zho** to tell simplified Chinese and traditional Chinese. It's hard to tell whether **chi** means the simplified one or traditional.

Seemingly, **chi** is derived from the first three characters of "Chinese", **zho** from the first three of "Zhōngwén".

The [wiki page of Chinese language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_language), as well as the following two links from ISO 639 documentation, [chi](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/documentation.asp?id=chi) and [zho](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/documentation.asp?id=zho), all tell us that **chi** is ISO 639-2/B, where the **B** stands for bibliographic, **zho** being ISO 639-2/T, **T** for terminological. The explanation of [the B and T codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2#B_and_T_codes) does not shed any light on traditional-or-simplified information the either.

But there is nowhere that I can refer to showing which one representing the traditional Chinese.

Comment: It seems that the designer chose the two labels deliberately, which as you've already pointed out that there's no way to tell which is TC or SC. I think the only way to figure out is to dump the database and examine some of the text data.

Comment: I'll bet that the designer takes "zho" to mean simplified Chinese and "chi" to mean traditional Chinese. Reason: "zhong" is a mainland-style "Pinyin" transcription, and in regions where traditional Chinese is used (such as Taiwan and Hong Kong), "Pinyin" is not the default phonetic system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

chi and zho stands for the Chinese language, but not one of its **writing forms**.

Specific codes for traditional Chinese and simplified Chinese widely in use being zh-Hant and zh-Hans respectively, specified by [IETF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) and also [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646).

The use of improvised codes "tc" and "sc", which abbreviate "Traditional Chinese" and "Simplified Chinese", are often observed too in Chinese websites.

So, just as @TactMayers said in the comment, I also think that the designer chose them deliberately, or simply due to misunderstanding.

*By the way, here may not be a right place for this question; [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) is more suitable.*

Answer (score 0):

According to [iso639-2](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php), the Chinese language is chi (B) or zho (T), where "B" for (bibliographic) and "T" for (terminology).

However, don't ask me about the difference, I really don't know.